# Music Bot Not Queueing Songs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using discord.py rewrite and I am making a do it all bot with cogs. One of the cogs I am using incorporates a music bot into it. I have the music playing but i'm trying to add a queue and any time it tries to add to the queue it says it does, but then after the current song is over it doesn't play anything. No errors, no anything. It just doesn't play. Any ideas

Code:

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
        if len(self.queue) == 0:
            self.queue[len(self.queue)] = player
            self.start_playing(ctx.voice_client, player)
            await ctx.send(f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n<:youtube:763374159567781890> **Now Playing:** ``{}'.format(player.title) + "``")
        else:
            self.queue[len(self.queue)] = player
            await ctx.send(f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n<:youtube:763374159567781890> **Added to queue:** ``{}'.format(player.title) + "``")
def start_playing(self, voice_client, player):
    self.queue[0] = player
    i = 0
    while i <  len(self.queue):
        try:
            voice_client.play(self.queue[i], after=lambda e: print(f' has finished playing.'))

        except:
            pass
        i += 1
```